# Access AWS Cognito user pool attributes in Appsync resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I would like to check if the current user has an attribute set, something like this:

```
#if(!${context.identity.claims.get("custom:organisation")})

... Do stuff

#end
```

I have tried the following:

```
#if (${context.identity.claims["custom:organisation"]})
#if (${context.identity["custom:organisation"]})
#if ($context.identity.claims["custom:organisation"])
#if ($util.isNull($context.identity.claims["custom:organisation"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use containsKey on the claims map such as below:

```
#if($context.identity.claims.containsKey("custom:organisation"))

... Do stuff

#end
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. You're right. My issue was that the user doing the queries did not have the access rights for the identity attribute. I had to write a Lambda function for getting the user attributes.

Comment: I am having a similar issue that my custom attribute is not visible in my Claims object when I pass on the Identity Claims to my Lambda.
I can the data in my IdToken in my App, but Appsync doesn't seem to forward the Attributes to the resolver template. Is there a separate setting for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
${context.identity.claims.get("custom:organisation")}
```